# Utilidad de localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Quería guardar una serie de datos del usuario, pero no usar base de datos. He visto la existencia de `localstorage` pero no termino de entenderlo.

Si el usuario escribe algo y yo lo almaceno con `localstorage`. Si mañana abre de nuevo la página, ¿aquello que escribió sigue allí? ¿O simplemente es por si refresca la página?

Comment: Carlos, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si solucionó tu problema /duda. Un saludo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Introducción:

La propiedad `localStorage` te permite acceder al objeto local `Storage`. `localStorage` es similar a `sessionStorage`. La única diferencia es que, mientras los datos almacenados en `localStorage` no tienen fecha de expiración, los datos almacenados en `sessionStorage` son eliminados cuando finaliza la sesion de navegación - lo cual ocurre cuando se cierra el navegador.

Con `sessionStorage` los datos persisten sólo en la ventana/tab que los creó, mientras que con `localStorage` los datos persisten entre ventanas/tabs con el mismo origen.

### Ventajas:

- LocalStorage puede ocupar entre 5 y 10MB dependiendo del navegador web.
- **No existe una caducidad para localStorage**, la información quedará
  almacenada hasta que se elimine expresamente. **Aunque se cierre el
  navegador.**

### Desventajas:

(Limitación)

- Sólo se puede almacenar cadenas de texto. O sea, no se puede guardar
  booleanos (true o false), tampoco guardar arrays, objetos,
  floats…. sólo strings.

**Solución:**
Los navegadores que soportan localStorage (o sea, los modernos), también tienen soporte para JSON. Gracias a JSON se puede convertir un objeto (o lo que esa) en cadena de texto y almacenarlo en el localStorage.

### Ejemplos:

```
localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan'); // Guardar Parametro

localStorage.setItem('objectKey', JSON.stringify(object)); //Guardar un objeto

var miGatoName = localStorage.getItem('miGato'); // Obtener Parametro

var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obcjetKey')) //Objetener un objeto

localStorage.removeItem('miGato'); //Eliminar Parametro

localStorage.clear(); // Limpia todo el Store
```

Comment: Una excelente respuesta!

Comment: Gracias @JonathanSchell. Si te soluciono la duda Carlos, agradecería la parques como correcta, es un buen gesto. Saludos.